# Spring Cloud Message channel without java interface

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring cloud stream application.Which receives messages from 20 AMQ queues.And post these to 20 Kafka topic using binder channels.for kafka outbound channels there is an interface  where each channel is configured like
@OUTOUT
MessageChannel channel01(); Problem is each time i add a topic i have to add it in this interface and redeploy the application.
is there any way i can just specify the newly created topic in yml file without changing this interface ? So my application will pick the new topic information.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently; adding bindings programmatically is on the road map.

Comment: Thanks Gary for reply